# Save Command Formatting Code Issue in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

Any time I try to quick save my React code, my code is immediately formatted and many errors appear everywhere.

This is what the code is reformatted to when I hit command + S on my Mac.

```
 import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return ( <
    div className = "App" >
    <
    header className = "App-header" >
    <
    img src = {
      logo
    }
    className = "App-logo"
    alt = "logo" / >
    <
    p >
    Hello my name is  <
    /p> <
    a className = "App-link"
    href = "https://reactjs.org"
    target = "_blank"
    rel = "noopener noreferrer" >
    Learn React <
    /a> <
    /header> <
    /div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Why is this happening?

> Update: The issue is with the prettier formatting extension. I disabled/uninstalled it and everything works fine now.

Comment: This happens when you format js files with HTML formatter.

Comment: if its not happening because of  `prettier` then u need to check VSCode settings `onSave`. look for ` "editor.formatOnSave"`what u have in it